# Apache Ignite Nifi Integration

Tags: apache-nifi, ignite

I am trying to create/use an apache ignite cache in nifi. I am using version 1.13.2 of nifi and i cannot find the PutIgniteCache and GetIgniteCache options. Please can someone assist me. Does this version support ignite?

Comment: drag a 'Processor' from top left into your canvas and type 'ignite' in search bar. you should see these processors.

Answer (score 1):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Migration+Guidance

**Migrating from 1.12.x to 1.13.x**

> Removed the following nar(s) from the convenience build.  They are still built and made available in maven repositories so you can add them to your deployment lib folder and use them if you like.  They include; nifi-livy-nar, nifi-livy-controller-service-api-nar, nifi-kafka-0-11-nar, nifi-beats-nar, **nifi-ignite-nar**

so, it's removed from nifi installation but you could download nar file from maven repo and put it into lib directory to make processors available

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-ignite-nar/1.13.2/nar

Comment: Hi So i am trying to get th getIgniteCache to work and havent had much success. Using nifi 1.13.x and ignite 2.10 the error is 

16:31:44 CATERROR37a7e1d5-0179-1000-23a0-4a52f9f6d792
GetIgniteCache[id=37a7e1d5-0179-1000-23a0-4a52f9f6d792] Failed to initialize ignite cache due to Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]

Comment: GetIgniteCache[Failure is due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]

Comment: look into the log with full error message. there could be some important information on why it can't start..

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Local node and remote node have different version numbers (node will not join, Ignite does not support rolling updates, so versions must be exactly the same) [locBuildVer=2.10.0, rmtBuildVer=1.6.0

Thats the error i found. Can i update nifi to use 2.10.0?

Comment: You could rebuild processor from sources substituting the version of ignite.

Comment: Can you please point me in the right direct to achieve this?